# Store function result to variable

Tags: javascript, variables, object

How can I store the result of a function to a variable?

In navigating an object that contains an array, I am looking for one value, *value1*, once that is found I want to get the value of one of its properties, *property1*.

The code I am using below is an example and is incorrect.

```
function loadSets(id){
   clworks.containers.find(function(i){
      return i.get('property1')===id;
   });
}
```

My intent is to navigate the object below:

```
clworks.containers
    containers[0].property0.id
    containers[1].property1.id
```

I am trying to determine how to find which item in the array has a property value equal to the id used in the function and then store it as a variable.

Comment: What is it you actually want to return? Also, there's no version of `find` in jQuery that accepts a *function*.

Comment: Where is the variable to which you want to store value?

Comment: that function isn't returning a value. It's merely looking up an element and then not using it. I'm not sure I understand what it is you actually want to do...

Comment: @JeremyT: It's not even doing that, `find` doesn't accept a function.

Comment: Who says that this is using jQuery? Couldn't it be anything?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion all, hopefully I didn't make it more confusing but I did update the question.

Comment: I think I understood the question now, I edited my answer accordingly. All those votes down are, I guess, for the completely weirdly wording. Sometimes wording a question correctly solves the problem itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply:

```
var myVar = loadSets(id);
```

### EDIT

Ok, as much as I understand your question now, your situation is the following:

1. You have an `array` containing objects called `containers`;
2. You want to iterate through this `array`, looking for the property `id` of the property `property1` which equals the one specified in the function called `loadSets(id)`;
3. Once found, store the object with the requested `id` in a variable.

Am I right?
If so, this should solve your problem:

```
// This function iterates through your array and returns the object
// with the property id of property1 matching the argument id
function loadSets( id ) {

    for(i=0; i < containers.length; i++) {

        if( containers[i].property1.id === id )
            return containers[i];

    }

    return false;

}
```

After this you just need to do what I said in the first answer to your question, triggering it however you want. I put up a [**quick JSBin for you**](http://jsbin.com/uxukaj/1). Try to put 10, or 20, in the `input` field and then hitting the *find* button; it will return the object you are looking for. Try putting any other number, it will return a *Not found*.

Comment: but loadSets isn't actually returning anything, so myVar will just be undefined

Answer (score 0):

Currently your function, loadSets, isn't actually returning anything and so you cannot store a result from it.

Try:

```
function loadSets(id){
   return Base.containers.find(function(i){
      return i.get('entityid')===id;
   });
}
```

And to get a result into a variable:

```
var result = loadSets(id);
```