# Assign the same random ID to three different keys

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have an ID generator. I would like the same ID to be assigned to 3 different keys in local-storage. Here is my code:

```
var ID = function () {
  return "_" + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
};

let user_name = document.getElementById("username");
let user_paswrd = document.getElementById("password");
let user_email = document.getElementById("email");

let store_data = () => {
  let i = 0;
  let input_username = localStorage.setItem(
    "username_nr" + ID(),
    user_name.value
  );
  let input_password = localStorage.setItem(
    "password" + ID(),
    user_paswrd.value
  );
  let input_email = localStorage.setItem("email" + ID(), user_email.value);
};
```

Now the generator assigns 3 different IDs to the keys "username", "password" and "email". How can I change this so that the generator assigns the same ID to the keys?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store function result to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117874/store-function-result-to-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than calling `ID` 3 times, each time generating a new ID, call it a single time and use the same value in each place that it's needed:

```
let store_data = () => {
  let id = ID();
  let i = 0;
  let input_username = localStorage.setItem(
    "username_nr" + id,
    user_name.value
  );
  let input_password = localStorage.setItem(
    "password" + id,
    user_paswrd.value
  );
  let input_email = localStorage.setItem("email" + id, user_email.value);
};
```